# WebView Delegate Not Invoked Even with Delegate=self and Also implemented UIWebView Delegate Protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

```
//NewCharts.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface NewCharts : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *loadView;
@end

//NewChart.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.title=@"Charts";
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.google.com"]];
    NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    _webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
    _webView.delegate=self;
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [_loadView startAnimating];

}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [_loadView stopAnimating];
}
```

//I did designing using xib file and connected its reference and delegates to file's Owner.  Still the delegate is not invoked.  I can only see the title of the page alone.

Comment: Have check putting break point in delegate methods?

Answer (score 1):

Load Url with **http://** , try following

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Call Self.webview.delegate = self before you load a request to webview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
self.title=@"Charts";
_webView.delegate=self;
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.google.com"]];
NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
_webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
}
```